# NAT not working on virtualbox running ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox-networking

I have a Windows 10 machine running Ubuntu 19.04 via Virtualbox 6.0.14.

Downloaded the iso, started a new machine and set network to "Nat".

This states results in no internet connection (when Bridged connection works).

How may I fix this?

It happens for other people:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1621890

Comment: probably you don't have defined network shared or something like that on virtualbox, on Windows, Ubuntu reconnized the bridge without doing anything if it's well-configured

Comment: Fresh installed everythign else though o.o what is defined network

Comment: you can find how to configure your NAT by reading VirtualBox Docs : https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: on the docs they say no configuration required

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1621890

This bugs sounds related...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. reinstalled same version of VB extension pack (latest) and it fixed it.
nothing else worked:) thanks.